# setUserCallbacks() to scene generated with newSubscene3d()

Tags: r, rgl

I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply the callback function set by setUserCallbacks() to scene generated with newSubscene3d(), except for the first scene.

In the example below, the added scene covers the bottom left of the original scene, but I can't figure out how to receive events in this part.

If the desired output is not HTML, several methods are possible. For example, One could create a scene that covers the entire viewport as the topmost scene to receive and process events on behalf of other scenes.

```
% R -e rmarkdown::render"('index.Rmd',output_file='index.html')"
```

````
---
title: "WebGL callback for a subscene created with newSubscene3d()"
output: html_document
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Callback implementation}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(rgl)
options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)
setupKnitr(autoprint = FALSE)
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
setupKnitr(autoprint = FALSE)
```

```{r}
sys.source("ex.R", envir = knit_global())

func1()

scene <- setUserCallbacks("left", 
      begin = "alert('AAA')", 
      update = "alert('BBB')", 
      end = "alert('CCC')",
      scene = scene3d(minimal = FALSE),
      subscene = scene3d(minimal = FALSE)$rootSubscene$id,
      applyToScene = TRUE,
      applyToDev = FALSE)

rglwidget(scene)
```
````

```
## This is ex.R.

library(rgl)

func1 <- function() {

  func1.dev.id <- open3d()
  func1.scene.1 <- subsceneInfo()$id

  par3d(windowRect = c(0, 0, 500, 500))
  view3d(theta=0, phi=0, zoom=1, fov=0)
  spheres3d(0,0,0, r=10, color = "green", alpha=0.5) # 
  spheres3d(500,500,0, r=10, color = "green", alpha=0.5) # 

  start <- list()

  begin <- function(x, y) {
    set3d(func1.dev.id, silent = TRUE)
    start$x <<- x
    start$y <<- y
    start$umat <<- par3d(subscene = func1.scene.1, "userMatrix")
    start$umat <<- par3d(subscene = func1.scene.2, "userMatrix")
  }

  update <- function(x, y) {
    viewport <- par3d("viewport")    
    x <- (x - start$x) / viewport[["width"]] / 1 # 1 is enpirically determined
    y <- (y - start$y) / viewport[["height"]] / 1
    umat <- start$umat
    umat <- umat %*% rotationMatrix(x, 0, 1, 0) # disp. y
    umat <- umat %*% rotationMatrix(y, 1, 0, 0) # disp. x

    par3d(subscene = func1.scene.1, userMatrix=umat)
    par3d(subscene = func1.scene.2, userMatrix=umat)
  }

  func1.scene.2 <- newSubscene3d(newviewport = c(0, 0, 200, 200))
  useSubscene3d(func1.scene.2)

  spheres3d(0,200,0, r=10, color = "red", alpha=0.5) # 
  spheres3d(200,0,0, r=10, color = "red", alpha=0.5) # 

  rgl.setMouseCallbacks(1, begin, update)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to set the callback on the root subscene when you write `subscene = scene3d(minimal = FALSE)$rootSubscene$id`.  You should use the id of the subscene you intended if it wasn't the root subscene.

Additionally, the expression `scene3d(minimal = FALSE)$rootSubscene$id` is more complicated than it needs to be.  The ids used in `rglwidget()` displays are the same ids as in the R session.  So if you want a callback on the subscene that you created with

```
func1.scene.2 <- newSubscene3d(newviewport = c(0, 0, 200, 200))
```

then you should save the value `func1.scene.2`, and use that value as the `subscene` argument in your call to `setUserCallbacks`.  The simplest way to do that is to return it from `func1`, and then use this code in your document:

```
sys.source("ex.R", envir = knit_global())

subsceneid <- func1()

scene <- setUserCallbacks("left", 
      begin = "alert('AAA')", 
      update = "alert('BBB')", 
      end = "alert('CCC')",
      scene = scene3d(minimal = FALSE),
      subscene = subsceneid,
      applyToScene = TRUE,
      applyToDev = FALSE)

rglwidget(scene)
```

I just tried your code with my fix, and discovered that there's a bug in one of the functions used by `setUserCallbacks()`, so my fix doesn't work.  It should work once version 1.2.15 or higher of `rgl` is available.  Try using the devel version (`remotes::install_github("dmurdoch/rgl")` should install it) once it is online.

Comment: I was able to get it working by setting the scene ID prepared with newSubscene3d(). I used the devel version of rgl.

By the way, I noticed that the ID of the subscene seems to be the same even if open3() is called in different code chunks. It seems preferable that it should be assigned without duplication within the browser window. I think it may be possible to work around this with the way knit is used, but I will report it anyway.

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion.  Perhaps it should be posted (with code) as an issue on the rgl GIthub page?

Comment: I couldn't explain it well in my previous post, so I'm trying another post.